# How to simulate HAND GESTURES using code in Android

Tags: android, simulation, gesture

I am developing a user guide tutorial for my app (a softkeyboard) and basically in the tutorial I need to programmatically simulate a set of several hand gestures including "click", "swipe", "long press and swipe" etc. I have no basic idea about how to achieve this and I have searched through the Internet but still did not get any useful findings.

So is there any one who kindly give me some advice on how to achieve this, if possible, please also give me a simple code example on this. Thanks so much, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* to simulate hand gestures for your tutorial. Just **pretend** that hand gestures were executed. For instance, say you want to teach the user to long press on a button to trigger some action. In that case, you could display a graphic or animation that directs users to the button and indicates a long press. You could, for instance, show an image of a finger that presses on the button. Then, trigger the action directly. You don't need to simulate the gesture, just go ahead and trigger the action directly.

Comment: This is a very inspiring suggestion. Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a tutorial or walk through of an App, I will suggest you to use some screen casting software, you dont have to do it programmatically.

There are on option **Show touches (on)** under settings > developer options >  keep it on. it will give you feedback where you have touched.

Here are some tools which can help to record screen cast

[Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/)

another userful tool is this:

[AndroidScreenCast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)

Other way will be in **After Effect**, after recoding your screencast add gestures in After Effect

Comment: Thx for your advice. The software you recommend me indeed works great if I just need to develop a pure tutorial. But in my case, the tutorial is not just a simple video or sth. It is an real activity indeed, which means I have to somewhat code to simulate some gestures in this tutorial activity so that it would show user how to use the app from the very beginning and later user could interact with the tutorial activity to do some simple actions. So I am afraid I still have to code for the simulation.

Comment: In that case easy way will be, just create an screencast and play it when user first time opens the app, It wont be interactive thou, Ya you are right there are no tutorial on web to code the simulation of App

Answer (score 0):

For swipe view you can refer this link: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html.
For button click just call onclicklistener() and id it to the button you want to use.
For long press, here is the code:(omit the numerals)

```
  import android.app.Activity;
    02
    import android.os.Bundle;
    03
    import android.view.View;
    04
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    05
    import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
    06
    import android.widget.TextView;
    07
    import android.widget.Toast;
    08

    09
    public class LongPress extends Activity {
    10

    11
     @Override
    12
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    13
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    14
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_long_press);
    15
      TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    16
      txtView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    17
       @Override
    18
       public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    19
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    20
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    21
          "You have pressed it long :)", 2000).show();
    22
        return true;
    23
       }
    24
      });
    25
      txtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    26
       @Override
    27
       public void onClick(View v) {
    28
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    29
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Long Enough :(",
    30
          1000).show();
    31
       }
    32
      });
    33
     }
    34

    35
    }
```